# Make a Radio Button required in Django Form

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form like this:

```
class ReportForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField()
    severity = forms.ChoiceField(label='Severity:', widget=forms.RadioSelect(), choices=SEVERITY_CHOICES, required=True)
```

I am using Crispy forms. If I am on my page that the form is rendering on, and I try to submit without filling anything in, it will tell me title is required. But it doesn't care if severity is filled in or not.

I have tried adding `required=True` to the field but that did not help.

```
SEVERITY_CHOICES= [
    ('Low', 'Low'),
    ('Medium', 'Medium'),
    ('High', 'High')
    ]
```

Comment: What are the `SEVERITY_CHOICES`? Is there a `None` in that?

Comment: I added it. Just some levels.

Answer (score 0):

HTML attributes are rendered from **form widgets**. You can either [pass additional attributes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#widget) to widget or use a customized widget:

```
class ReportForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField()
    severity = forms.ChoiceField(
                   label='Severity:', 
                   widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={"required": True}),
                   choices=SEVERITY_CHOICES, 
                   required=True
               )

# or
class MyRadioSelect(RadioSelect):
    is_required = True

class ReportForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField()
    severity = forms.ChoiceField(label='Severity:', 
                                widget=forms.MyRadioSelect(),
                                choices=SEVERITY_CHOICES, required=True)
```